# Datastructure for a log search service?

Tags: data-structures

A few months back, i was asked to design a service which takes a start and end time interval and lists down the number of exceptions/errors grouped by the exception type/code. Basically the intention was to create or use an existing data structure for an efficient search. Here is what I coded.

```
public class ErrorDetail{
  private int code;
  private String message;
}

public class ExceptionSearchService
{
private Map<Long, ErrorDetail> s = new TreeMap<Long, ErrorDetail>();
public ArrayList<ErrorDetail> getErrors(long start, long end){
 ErrorDetail e1 = find(start, s);
 ErrorDetail e2 = find(end, s);
 //do an in order traversal between e1 and e2 and add it to an array list and return  
}

public void addError(long time, ErrorDetail e){
s.put(time,e);
}

}
```

I realized that i should not have mentioned a TreeMap, instead should have had my own class like TreeNode but the idea was to have a tree structure and a distributed one because we are talking about thousands of services serving millions of request per minute and generating error.

Could i have used a better data structure in this case ?

Comment: Are you assuming that all of the errors from "millions of request per minute" will fit into memory? Can we assume that calls to `addError` are made in chronological order (i.e. `time` for call x+1 will always be greater than `time` for call x)? Is the data structure being updated at the same time you're querying it?

Comment: @JimMischel - It will not fit into a single machine, also the data structure is being updated while querying.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're wanting to build. Are you trying to build a data structure that contains the errors? So that when a service gets an error, the service somehow logs that error to your data structure? And you'll then have a separate interface for people to query that data structure?

Comment: @JimMischel - yes its like services logs the error into the data structure and at the same time, there is an interface which queries the data structure to get all errors between an interval start and interval end

Comment: Isn't this what databases are for?